# Oracle DMS sample using Android & SQLite?

Tags: android, oracle, sqlite, dms

Is there a codesample and a tutorial for this? Ideally one published by Oracle.

simple_sync_android doesn't use SQLite at all.

This is the best I could find and it's somewhat insufficient in detail: http://oracledms.blogspot.com/

?

This looks kinda hopeful:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/database-mobile-server/documentation/dms-quickstart-2186744.pdf

> > > >
> > >           4 Transport Demo
> > >           Once DMS and MDK are installed, you are ready to move on to the next step - the Mobile
> > >           Server synchronization and the application development and deployment models.
> > >           For more information, see your mobile client platform-specific version of the Transport demo
> > >           tutorial included in the MDK:
> > >           Win32/WinCE: \Mobile\Sdk\samples\dotnet\bdb\transport\doc\Transport Tutorial.doc
> > >           -> For Android: \Mobile\Sdk\samples\android\transport\Transport Tutorial.pdf
> > >           -> For iOS: \Mobile\Sdk\samples\ios\transport\Transport Tutorial.pdf
> > >       <<<<

Only problem here is that it's not included in my install?! (I'm running 11.3.x)
?? 
-JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. I found it.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/database-mobile-server/documentation/index.html

look closely near the middle of the page and you'll see:
    ***Transport demo package (zip file)***

Comment: Instead you can download directly by click on [this link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-mobile-server/documentation/transport-2259363.zip)